# How does a dns client know a subdomain is delegated to another nameserver

Tags: dns, protocols

Let's say I own the domain `example.com` and I have a nameserver that is responsible for resolving requests for that domain.

And now, I want to delegate requests for `sub.example.com` to a different nameserver, just like the `.com` nameserver delegates `example.com` requests to my nameserver.

How does the client that wants to resolve for example `a.sub.example.com` know, which server is responsible for resolving this domain?

I have read a lot on the internet about it, but mostly it was explained way to less detailed. For example, I know that this can be done using a NS-record. But I want to know it more specific.

I'm currently experimenting with two self-written dns servers, that use a low-level dns library and only has hard-coded dns-records. It currently does 2 things:

1. return any record that matches the query exactly (domain name & type)
2. log the requested domain name & type

The server responsible for `example.com` currently only has a NS-record for `sub.example.com` which points to the address of the second server, let's say `vserver1000.myhoster.com`.

The second server only has an A-record for `a.sub.example.com` pointing to some IP-Address.

But when I try to resolve this IP-Address using `nslookup a.sub.example.com`, only the first nameserver gets requests. And the requests are only of type A or AAAA. But if the client does not make any NS-requests, how should it find out that another server would have been responsible for resolving this domain name?

Should the first server proactively send NS-records as answer to an A-request? Or should the server answer that it's not authorative for this domain?

How does this actually work?

Comment: Some info about this should be in rfc1034, e.g.  chapter 4.3.2

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Address_resolution_mechanism

Comment: @Dusan Bajic that section does not describe it. I've already read this multiple times.

Comment: @nox thx, it worked :)